# Twitter API, from database to twitter

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, oauth, cron

I wish to send a tweet (status, update) to / from ONE PARTICULAR twitter account hourly from a mysql database. I have messed around with the twitter api & oAuth before and it is a real big headache. I just want to have one account hardwired into the code. The hourly part means automation / CRON, however i've never messed with CRON. I see all of the pieces of what I'm trying to accomplish I just need a little shove in the right direction. Any help / tutorials / pointers regarding this would be a great help. PHP is my main language of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Twitter:**

1.) Go to dev.twitter.com, login with the account you want to use, create an app, then under app settings write down consumer key, consumer secret and oauth token/ouath token secret.

2.) use this script https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

```
$client = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_secret);
```

Then use API documentation for whatever you need https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

ex. Tweeting: `$client->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'tweet text'));`

**Cron:**

Most shared hostings provide an easy-to-setup cron from cpanel, check it first. If it's not available, then you need to login via SSH and use `crontab -e` then for once every hour add `0 * * * *`

Read up on it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron